# Color changes to Green, but not back to Red | Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make a part, change from red to green using `BrickColor.new` in my script. It only changes to green, but not back to red. Here is my code:

```
Keydoor.colorchange.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Lime green")
wait(2)
Keydoor.colorchange.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really red")
```

I have tried using color3 instead of BrickColor, but it still doesn't work:

```
Keydoor.colorchange.BrickColor = Color3.new(0, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console or Output window?

Comment: No, there is nothing in the output window relating to the part.

Comment: Where is the script located?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try `BrickColor.new(Color3.new(1, 0, 0.0156863))`